# Presentation activity on android sdk

Tags: android

please see the image for understand what I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC4ZR.png

Activity 1 **FULLSCREEN + NO TITLE BAR**

Activity 2 **No FULLSCREEN + TITLE BAR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To the onCreate() of your first Activity you want in full screen mode. Do nothing else to the rest of them. That's it.

Comment: I try this but all activities became fullscreen

Comment: Then you're adding it to all your Activities. I have personally just tried out this code on a Galaxy Nexus and it only makes the Activity its been added to fullscreen. All other Activities are still normal.

Comment: there's only one onCreate, I add the code before setContentView(..act1) after 10seconds I make new setContentView(..act2), but the act2 also fullscreen :(

Comment: So then you're not using multiple Activities. You're still using the same Activity, just changing its content. The Activity remains the same.

Comment: How to change to multiple Activities ??

Comment: Read up on that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)